# Can UDP checksum be tampered with? ( or is it 100% reliable?)

Tags: security, udp, checksum, packet

My question is simply, if I check an internet check sum for a UDP packet and then receive a packet and it matches, can I be 100% sure there are no bit errors? (deliberate or accidental)

As in: I know UPD packet error checking prevents false negatives, but how do false positives (if possible) occur?

False positive == flagging it as ok after check sum comparison but there is in fact still errors.

False negatives == flagging as an error guarantees an error.

(NOTE:I didn't define false positive, and negative to aid my the person answering me as much as to help make this question as useful as possible for others later down the road. I in no way wish to insult anyone's intelligence.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum

Comment: Sorry, I sort of redefined my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot be sure.  There are multiple different packet contents that will have the same checksum.  This is a trivial consequence of the [*pigeonhole principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: Thank you this does answer how false positives occur in this case!